# What does "乗るもので" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 移動経路はこのように二つあります。前者は電車に乗るもので、後者はバスに乗る必要があります。
>
> As posted on the guide box, there are two ways to go.
> You take a train with the first and a bus with the second.

How to parse 乗るもので here ? It doesn't seem to be the もので of "cause/reason".

Comment: What is the previous sentence?  Any other further context you'd like to add?

Comment: It's from a site to learn japanese grammar so there isn't a context, sorry.

Comment: What, it has no context, and it's on a site for learning Japanese grammar? The 1st sentence should have the subject, then... as in 「経路図のように、 **経路は**二つあります。 / **行き方は**二つあります。」 (And.. are you sure it's 経路**箱** , not 経路図, 路線図 or something ? )

Comment: I see, thank you. The site is pretty new and not totally perfect, so it's really not impossible that there are some mistakes => https://imgur.com/HVXu8Md

Comment: @Jirei Ahh.. so it should be a typo for 「移動経路**は**　**このように**　二つあります。」"There are two routes, like this."

Comment: That's why I couldn't find more than only one occurence for 移動経路箱, thank you Chocolate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to parse 乗るもので here? It doesn't seem to be the もので of "cause/reason".

You're right, the もので doesn't mean "cause/reason".

The で is the continuative form (or the te-form) of the copula だ (or です).
<sup>(Grammatically speaking, the continuative form of です is でし and the te-form is でして.)</sup>
The もの is a noun (物) for "(some)thing", "what" or "the one". もの can function like a pronoun and here it refers to 移動経路.

So your example can be rephrased as:
「移動経路はこのように二つあります。前者は電車に乗るもの**だ/です。そして**、後者はバスに乗る必要があります。」
↓
「移動経路はこのように二つあります。前者は電車に乗るもの**で**、後者はバスに乗る必要があります。」
<sup>(電車に乗る modifies もの as a relative clause.)</sup>
"There are two routes, as you see. / like this. The former is the one with which you take a train, and as for the latter, you need to take a bus."

Answer (score 0):

The "もの" here refers to "経路".　So, "前者は電車に乗るもので、後者はバスに乗る必要があります" can be rephrased as "前者は電車に乗る経路で、後者の経路ではバスに乗る必要があります".